# HoloLens cannot connect to OpcUa server

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, hololens, opc-ua

I want to connect to the OpcUa server through the APP on HoloLens and read the node's data. It works on Unity and works fine, but it can't connect to the OpcUa server in HoloLens. I use the OpcUaHelper plugin, which has a simple OpcUa client and supports .Net Core and .Net Standard 2.0.

Unity's settings are:

Scripting Runtime  Version: .Net 4.X Equivalent

Scripting Backend: IL2CPP

Api Compatibility Level : .Net 4.X

My code are shown below.
Does anyone know what the reason is? 
Or have anyone tried to connect the Opc Ua server in HoloLens?

The version of the software I am using is:

1.Unity 2018 3.11f

2.Mixed Reality Toolkit v2.0.0 RC1

3.Visual Studio 2017

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.Input;
using OpcUaHelper;
using Opc.Ua;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public void OpcUaConnector()
    {
        OpcUaClient m_OpcUaClient = new OpcUaClient();
        //m_OpcUaClient.UserIdentity = new UserIdentity("user", "password");
        string OpcUa_Test = "opc.tcp://118.24.36.220:62547/DataAccessServer";
        m_OpcUaClient.ConnectServer(string.Format("{0}", OpcUa_Test));
        try
        {
            //Read the same type of data from multiple nodes

            List<NodeId> nodeIds = new List<NodeId>();
            nodeIds.Add(new NodeId("ns=2;s=Machines/Machine A/Name"));
            nodeIds.Add(new NodeId("ns=2;s=Machines/Machine B/Name"));
            nodeIds.Add(new NodeId("ns=2;s=Machines/Machine C/Name"));
            List<DataValue> dataValues = m_OpcUaClient.ReadNodes(nodeIds.ToArray());
            AnlagenName_A.text = string.Format("{0}", dataValues[0]);
            AnlagenName_B.text = string.Format("{0}", dataValues[1]);
            AnlagenName_C.text = string.Format("{0}", dataValues[2]);

            //foreach (string tag in Tags)
            //{
            //    string value = m_OpcUaClient.ReadNode<string>(tag);
            //}
        }

        //    //Read data from a single node
        //    //string value = m_OpcUaClient.ReadNode<string>("ns=2;s=Machines/Machine B/Name");
        //    //Console.WriteLine("{0}", value);
        //    //Console.ReadKey();
        //}
        catch
        {
            Debug.Log("Connected Failed");
        }
    }
```

I hope to successfully connect to the OpcUa server and read the node data.

Comment: Can you connect to other places but just not the OpcUa server?  Did you check the Internet Client and Internet Server checkboxes?

Comment: @slaphshot33324 I have connected to the Mysql server without any problems. The Internet Client in Player Setting is also confirmed to be checked.

Comment: Ok, next thing I would look at is the port you are connecting on.  Is that port open for outbound?

Comment: @slaphshot33324 Sorry, I didn't understand which port you are talking about. Is Setting of this port in Unity?

Comment: opc.tcp://118.24.36.220:62547 The port is 62547

Comment: @slaphshot33324 yes, this port is open for outbound. I can connect to this server in Unity and get the node data. But importing this project into HoloLens will not work, no data is obtained, and maybe it is not connected to the OpcUa server.

Comment: Right, i'm wondering if this port is blocked from the Hololens since it works in Unity but as soon as you port to Hololens you cannot connect.

Comment: @slaphshot33324 Oh，how can I check if this port is blocked in HoloLens?

Comment: A quick Google of the issue came up with this: Currently you need to enable the following capabilities in Package.appxmanifest:
Private networks (Client and Server)
Internet (Client and Server)
Internet (Client)

Now, the application should be able to connect to an any specified port.

Comment: @slaphshot33324 Ok, I will check these option in VS2017, but I have already opened these options in the Unity settings.

Comment: @slaphshot33324 I checked these options in Visual Studio2017, all of them are open, but still can't connect to OpcUa server.